# React.js display image from saved API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I want to do a simple image fetch from API. My goal is to display random image from API. Now it says "Data" is not defined. I have no idea why it does that because my `console.logs` were working before trying to show it on page.

This is my App.js

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Dog from './doggo';

//Main component
function App() {

  const [dogs, setDog] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
      getDog();
  }, []);
  //Function to get data
  const getDog = async () => {
      //Fetch from url
      const response = await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random");
      //Store answer in data
      const data = await response.json();
      //Place data.message in setDog
      setDog(data.message);

      console.log(data.status);
      //data.message contains image url
      console.log(data.message);
  };
  return(
      <div>
          <h1>Press button to see your future dog!</h1>
          <button type="submit">See your dog!</button>
          <Dog
            image={data.message}
          />
      </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: variable `data` is not available outside the `getDog` function, you probably meant to use `dogs` state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reformatted you code a bit to take care of some issues.

As other commenters have stated, `data` is out of scope where you're trying to access it. (It's only available inside of the `getDog()` function.)

```
export default function App() {
  const [dog, setDog] = useState();

  const getDog = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random");
    const data = await response.json();
    setDog(data.message);
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Press button to see your future dog!</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          getDog();
        }}
      >
        See your dog!
      </button>
      {dog ? <Dog image={dog} /> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working Codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-silence-g7g00?file=/src/App.js:153-878)

Answer (score 0):

use `{dogs}` instead of `{data.message}` in `<Dog image={data.message}/>` data is a variable only for the getDog() function.